# How to unit test a Factory class which depends on a constant?

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

So I have this factory class implementing Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface:

```
class GatewayFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = new Config($serviceLocator->get('ApplicationConfig'));
        if ('phpunit' === APPLICATION_ENV) {
            return new Gateway($config, new Mock());
        }
        return new Gateway($config);
    }

}
```

It always returns Gateway instance but adds a mock adapter as second parameter when APPLICATION_ENV constant is "phpunit".

I am running my unit tests with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/unit/Bootstrap.php" colors="true" backupGlobals="false" backupStaticAttributes="false" syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="mysuite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <const name="APPLICATION_ENV" value="phpunit"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Therefor APPLICATION_ENV is set to "phpunit". How can I write a test for a case when the constant is different?

I can test for the if condition but I cannot figure out how to test for a case when it doesn't go inside the if condition:

```
class GatewayFactoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testCreateServiceReturnsGatewayWithMockAdapterWhenApplicationEnvIsPhpunit()
    {
        $factory = new GatewayFactory();
        $gateway = $factory->createService(Bootstrap::getServiceManager());
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Mock', $gateway->getAdapter());
    }

    public function testCreateServiceReturnsGatewayWithSockerAdapterWhenApplicationEnvIsNotPhpunit()
    {
        // TODO HOW TO DO THIS?
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use an environment var instead of a constant? That way you could use `putenv` either side of the createService call in your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be writing code that's only used in tests. You should write code that can be tested.

You could do something like this.

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $mock = null)
{
    $config = new Config($serviceLocator->get('ApplicationConfig'));

    return new Gateway($config, $mock);
}
```

I would have a look at the `Gateway` class too, though. Why does it sometimes need an extra object?